# How to use an parent instance to replace child object's parent in python

Tags: python, class, sockets, inheritance, super

Here is my code:

```
import socket
import select
class My_socket(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self, soc = None):
        if soc == None:
            socket.socket.__init__(self, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            ....
        else:
            # how to use soc to initialize or replace parent part

....
rs, ws, es = select.select([my_socket_instance],[],[])
....
```

I want to create a my_socket class which has more functions, and when u pass no argument to its constructor, it will initialize its parent part automatically, but when u pass a socket instance as argument, it uses it as its parent so that my_socket can still work fine like just a socket ( for instance as an input of select function)

More specifically I met this problem when I get the (conn, addr) as a return of  socket.accept(), and conn is socket type, I want to turn it to my_socket type, how to achieve that

thanks

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Change your constructor to: `def __init__(self, soc=None): socket.socket.__init__(self, _sock=soc)`

Comment: Sorry to forget to mention that I'm using Python 2.7.14. And t.m.adam's code do solve my problem, thanks a lot. But what does the _sock variable mean, what's the mechanism here? Is it related to python's inheritance mechanism or just the Python's socket implementation

Comment: Path `\python\Lib\socket.py`, line 180, in `_socketobject.__init__`. The constructor accepts a socket in the `_sock` parameter. Just follow the code.